# Is actionscript case sensitive?

Tags: actionscript, case-sensitive

`on(rollover)` and `on(rollOver)` both work,but I'm not sure if it's case sensitive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple Google search has turned up: AS 1.0 was NOT case-sensitive, AS 2.0 and 3.0 ARE case-sensitive.

But,
 Have you double checked your variable usage to make sure that you don't have variables with those names in scope?

Comment: My version is ActionScript 1.0&2.0

Comment: Well, you have to choose one or the other during compilation, don't you?